# Modal won't appear on click but will disappear on click just fine

Tags: css, wordpress, modal-dialog, divi-theme

Here is the page in question:
https://www.alchemycreative.studio/test-layout-3/

The little hamburger icon points to "#openModal" but it does not work unless you open it in a new tab. It will disappear fine, however, when you click the X, which points to "#".

They both use the same technique. Can anyone tell me why it's not working for the hamburger? The modal is also doing a weird thing where it comes and goes briefly after page load.

The instructions I followed are here, complete with a demo:
https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Below is my CSS, which takes out all the extra styling:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is you HTML structure which you haven't shown us. Please include enough code for us to see the problem see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Look carefully at your HTML in comparison to the demo. In the demo the anchor element and the modal div are siblings. They aren't in your code.

Comment: I'm using a page builder, so while I've tried to recreate the elements in the instructions, I cannot access the HTML. Could you elaborate on what you mean by the anchor element and modal div being "siblings"? The hamburger hyperlinks to "#openModal" and the modal div's ID is #openModal.

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to look at the hamburger and the modal elements. Then do the same on the demo. In the demo the two are next to each other, not only siblings (children of the same parent) but adjacent. This means the first can alter the styling of the second (so sets opacity 1 so it can be seen). In your code they are not children of the same parent.